# Agora SDK React Native - how to create new Video Call channel for each user?

Tags: react-native, agora.io

Currently, I am able to create temp token for audio/video streaming in my Agora Console. In that way, all of my users *are connected to the same channel*. What I want to achieve is to somehow programmatically create a **separate** channel for each call for my users so that user **A** will be in call with user **B**, and user **C** will be in a call with user **D**.

[image]

**Here is the official code sample of react-native-agora (on line 91):**

https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/react-native-agora/blob/master/example/src/examples/advanced/LiveStreaming.tsx

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [agora-token-service](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-token-service) repo to deploy a token server, or add it to your own backend using your [preferred language](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/tree/master/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey). Once you have a token server deployed, you can then send a request using an arbitrary channel name (for example use UUID) to receive a token for that channel.

If you're using the token-servie repo, you can send a GET request to this route `your_server.com/rtc/<channelName>/publisher/uid/<uid>/` with your UID and channelName to get a token.

People on the same channel can communicate with each other, you can have as many channels as you need.